# how to get iBooks on Iphone4

Tags: itunes, iphone, pdf, books

I want to use iBooks to read the pdf I have synchronized on my old Iphone 4 (iOS7). I can't install it from the appstore on my phone because the latest version of iBooks require iOS 10.

[image]

It says "This app needs iOS 10.0 or later"

But according to [this link](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201478), I can install it through iTunes and then synch it with my phone to get an older version.

Except for the fact that in iTunes (latest version) on my 2 computers (Win10) I can't click on the "get it" button, it is grayed out like shown on the capture :

But I can download any other app without any problem.

So how can I get iBooks on an Iphone 4 OR any free app wich allow me to read pdf (not from links or mail, but the one I've synch with my phone) ?

Comment: IBooks doesn't require iOS10 because that hasn't been released yet. You should be able to install iBooks on any iOS device from iOS5 on up, I think.

Comment: @fbara I'm gonna get you a screenshot.

Comment: That will be helpful. The link you included says: "You can use iBooks on your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch. For some features, you might need to meet these requirements: To use iBooks 4.0 or later, you need iOS 8 or later. To use iBooks 3.2, you need iOS 7. To use iBooks with iCloud, you need iOS 6 or later. To download from the iBooks Store or use iCloud features, you need an Apple ID and Internet access. To listen to audiobooks in iBooks, you need iOS 8.4 or later."  If you have iOS7 you should be able to install it.

Comment: For the mean time, you can install Documents 5 by Readdle.
https://appsto.re/ca/Vw_Vv.i   -- it will allow for any type of file to be downloaded, and has built in PDF reader.

Comment: @bret7600 seems nice but require iOS 8...

Answer (score 1):

As the above comment states, you do not need iOS 10 to download iBooks. However, given the info in your screenshot, it is possible that iBooks is not available in your country.

EDIT: *iOS 10 is not out. I have no idea why it would require you have it.*

Please review the following article and make sure your device is compatible.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201478

**SEE ADDITIONAL EDIT BELOW**

[image]

I just looked at the App Store, and it DOES appear you need iOS 10!

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ibooks/id364709193?mt=8

[image]

Comment: So I'm not going crazy. Could they have disabled the downloads till iOS10 is out ?

Comment: I'm an Apple Developer. I'm going to see what more I can find out. This is really weird.

Comment: @TMHahn Yes, any news ?

Comment: @Marine1 iOS 10 is out and this should work now. I don't believe there is any way to get iBooks to work on a device running iOS 9 unless they already had it installed. I do not believe the older version of iBooks is available.

Comment: Is this what is called programmed product obsolescence? I just get an Iphone 4 and my last mobile phone lasted 6 years and could still be used.

Comment: @Marine1 I think it has more to do with the time and effort required to support a second version of an app. Many apps will not work on the iPhone 4 now. I recently read that less than 1% of the iPhones being used are iPhone 4. It doesn't make financial sense to support something that almost no one is using.